# Extract values from JSON complex object

Tags: r, json

I've a json file as shown below. I would like to extract the data into a R dataframe as follows. See the json object, that has a list of values for various dates. I would like to extract those values into the dataframe. Can you kindly help, on how I should build this?

**Output Dataframe**

```
Jan-18 a 5
Jan-18 b 0
Jan-18 c 9
Jan-18 d 0
Jan-18 e 5
Jan-19 a 4
Jan-19 b 0
Jan-19 c 26
Jan-19 d 0
Jan-19 e 35
```

value_headers = **['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']**

**Input JSON content:**

```
{
    "default": {
        "timelineData": [
            {
                "time": "1610928000",
                "formattedTime": "Jan 18, 2021",
                "formattedAxisTime": "Jan 18",
                "value": [
                    5,
                    0,
                    9,
                    0,
                    5
                ],
                "hasData": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false,
                    true
                ],
                "formattedValue": [
                    "5",
                    "0",
                    "9",
                    "0",
                    "5"
                ]
            },
            {
                "time": "1611014400",
                "formattedTime": "Jan 19, 2021",
                "formattedAxisTime": "Jan 19",
                "value": [
                    4,
                    0,
                    26,
                    0,
                    35
                ],
                "hasData": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false,
                    true
                ],
                "formattedValue": [
                    "4",
                    "0",
                    "26",
                    "0",
                    "35"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "averages": [
            5,
            1,
            34,
            25,
            25
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse could be something like:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

json_dt <- fromJSON('{
    "default": {
        "timelineData": [
            {
                "time": "1610928000",
                "formattedTime": "Jan 18, 2021",
                "formattedAxisTime": "Jan 18",
                "value": [
                    5,
                    0,
                    9,
                    0,
                    5
                ],
                "hasData": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false,
                    true
                ],
                "formattedValue": [
                    "5",
                    "0",
                    "9",
                    "0",
                    "5"
                ]
            },
            {
                "time": "1611014400",
                "formattedTime": "Jan 19, 2021",
                "formattedAxisTime": "Jan 19",
                "value": [
                    4,
                    0,
                    26,
                    0,
                    35
                ],
                "hasData": [
                    true,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false,
                    true
                ],
                "formattedValue": [
                    "4",
                    "0",
                    "26",
                    "0",
                    "35"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "averages": [
            5,
            1,
            34,
            25,
            25
        ]
    }
}')

tibble(
  time = json_dt$default$timelineData$formattedTime,
  value = json_dt$default$timelineData$formattedValue
) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(
    letter = letters[1:n()],
    value = as.integer(value),
    time = str_replace(time, ",.*", ""),
    time = str_replace(time, " ", "-")
  )
```